# Как вызвать метод хаба (SignalR) через api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, чат

[ссылка на проект (github)](https://github.com/derkode/ChatServerApi)

Делаю сервер для анонимного высоконагруженного чата, используя библиотеку `SignalR`. Это мой первый опыт в подобных проектах.

Сделал хаб и все необходимые методы:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private static List<User> AllUsers = new List<User>();
    private static ChatContext db = new ChatContext();        

    public void Join(string userName, string groupId)
    {            
        var userId = Context.ConnectionId;
        var currentUser = new User(userId, userName, groupId);
        if (!AllUsers.Any(x => x.ConnectionId == userId ))
        {
            AllUsers.Add(currentUser);                
            var groupUsers = AllUsers.Where(x => x.GroupId == groupId); 

            //посылаем сообщение текущему пользователю
            Clients.Caller.OnJoined(userId, userName, groupUsers);

            //посылаем сообщение всем пользователям группы, кроме текущего
            Clients.Group(groupId, userId).onNewUserConnected(userId, userName);
        }
    }

    public void SendMessage(string msg)
    {
        var currentUser = AllUsers.Where(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId).Single();
        Clients.Group(currentUser.GroupId).AddMessage(currentUser.Name, msg);
        db.Messages.Add(new Message { String = msg });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Но вот не знаю **как вызывать эти методы через запросы клиентов, которые будут, как я правильно понимаю, приходить посредством** `/api/Join`, `/api/SendMessage`? Согласно техническому заданию сервер должен быть построен на `ASP.NET Web API 2`, ну собственно на нем и делаю.

Немного начал делать свой API-контроллер:

```
public class ChatController : ApiController
{
    private ChatContext db = new ChatContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Group>> GetAllGroups()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> db.Groups);       
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public async Task Join(string userName, string groupId)
    {
        // как мне вызвать свой метод Join из моего хаба ChatHub?
    }
}
```

**Что сказал Google?**

1. Вот по этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395201/call-a-hub-method-from-a-controllers-action) говорится о контексте хаба. И сделав, все что там говорится, я думал что смогу передать запрос, пришедший на api, дальше в свой хаб (ChatHub), посредством `hubContext.Join()` или `hubContext.SendMessage()`. Ничего такого не произошло.
2. [Здесь](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/884647/Web-app-using-Web-API-SignalR-and-AngularJS) чувак говорит о создании абстрактного класса от которого у нас затем будет наследоваться наш api-контроллер и мы без проблем сможем использовать свой хаб. Но я ничего так и не понял - такое ощущение, что он кусок кода там проглотил.

[ссылка на проект (github)](https://github.com/derkode/ChatServerApi)

Answer (score 3):

Как много ответов за 7 месяцев)

Думаю проблема решена, но отвечу как сам понимаю (у меня работало при тесте).

1. Лучше не использовать апи для взаимодействия хаба и клиента. Только
   если по-другому никак.
2. Клиент коннекшен для хаба в хаб классе и апи контроллере будет разным.  Поэтому часть методов не будет доступна в апи. Например, оповестить калера.
   Т.е. нельзя написать (код в хабе) `Clients.Caller.myTestJsMethod("Hi");`

В апи придется писать так:

```
     public class TestApiController : ApiController

{
    private IHubContext _hub;
    public TestApiController()
    {
        _hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHubClass>();

    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult TestApiCallConnection(string connectionId)
    {
        var message = "Hi connection user";

_hub.Clients.Client(connectionId).testInJsClientSideApiCall(message);
        return Json(message);
    }

}
```

Для оповещения всех пользователей можно написать так:

```
 public IHttpActionResult TestApiCallAll()
    {
        var message = "Hi connection user";
        _hub.Clients.All.testInJsClientSideApiCall(message);
        return Json(message);
    }
```

Чтобы контекст вызвался в контроллере, необходимо настроить конфиг в Startup.cs. 
Пример с ди:
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { get; private set; }
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app )
        {

```
        DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
        ConfigureAuth(app);



        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableDetailedErrors = true,
          // моя имплементация ди
            Resolver = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = NinjectWebCommon.GetResolver()
        };
        _initCaches((IDiResolver)hubConfiguration.Resolver).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        GlobalHost.Configuration.MaxIncomingWebSocketMessageSize = 10485760;//10mb
        //hubConfiguration.EnableJavaScriptProxies = false; default is true

        app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);


    }}
```

Чтобы не плодить код, все действия лучше делать в отдельных сервисах, а в контроллере и хабе уже их вызывать.

Про ди и сигнал есть подробный гайд [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).

ps   разумеется в апи экшенах ничего ретартить не обязательно методы могут быть воидами все оповещение осуществляет IHubContext на указанный ид группу  или всем и лиш для того чтобы увидить в отдельной вкладке браузера тот же результат и сравнить с вкладкой клиента стоит делать запросы с ретарном

pss group

```
public IHttpActionResult TestApiGroupCallAll(string groupId)
{
    var message = "Hi connection user";
    _hub.Clients.Group(groupId).testInJsClientSideApiCall(message);
    return Json(message);
}
```